# How can install vim on the new debian12 version?

Tags: debian, software-installation, vim

Version conflict when to install vim on my debian12:

```
sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.1.0875-5+deb10u5) but 2:9.0.1378-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i remove `vim-common`:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim-common
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install vim       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ncurses-base : Breaks: vim-common (< 2:9.0.1000-2) but 2:8.1.0875-5+deb10u5 is to be installed
 ncurses-term : Breaks: vim-common (< 2:9.0.1000-2) but 2:8.1.0875-5+deb10u5 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How to install vim in debian12 then?

```
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi-R4A-srv 6.1.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.27-1 (2023-05-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: is this Debian 12 a clean install or an upgrade from Bullseye? what version is shown for `apt show vim`? have you done an `apt update`? Do you have any apt sources you've added yourself?

Comment: What platform are you on? I had no problem installing vim after a new install of Debian 12 on x86_64. Like Jaromanda X, I wonder if you did something different. I messed up my upgrade from 11, so I installed fresh.